# How do I disable fireworks on the main menu in 1.15.0?

Tags: beat-saber

Beat Saber's 3rd anniversary update (1.15.0) added fireworks to the game's main menu that go off every time you start the game. Is there any way to disable these firework sound effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu fireworks were removed in Beat Saber 1.16.0, which released alongside the [Interscope Mixtape DLC](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/620980/view/3001065803744427928) on May 27, 2021.

User-created mods made for 1.15.0 appear to still be compatible with 1.16.0, so updating shouldn't cause any issues.